# Swift - Array of Any to Array of Strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, casting

How can I cast an array initially declared as container for Any object to an array of Strings (or any other object)?
Example :

```
var array: [Any] = []
.
.
.
array = strings // strings is an array of Strings
```

I receive an error : "Cannot assign value of type Strings to type Any"

How can I do?

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can try casting strings as! [AnyObject] to use it in array reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the type of a variable once it has been declared, so you have to create another one, for example by safely mapping `Any` items to `String` with `flatMap`:

```
var oldArray: [Any] = []
var newArray: [String] = oldArray.flatMap { String($0) }
```

Answer (score 5):

Updated to Swift 5

```
var arrayOfAny: [Any] = []
var arrayOfStrings: [String] = arrayOfAny.compactMap { String(describing: $0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this synatic sugar grammar. Still one line of code :)

```
var arr: [Any] = []
var strs = [String]()
arr = strs.map {$0 as! [String]}
```

Comment: In my test in playground, I didn't have to cast it to `[String]`. Is it really needed? And I think you mean `strs.map` instead of `arr.map`? :)

Comment: I think that question is "can compiler see arr as [String]" like you have re-declared it. Btw I haven't tested this code.

Comment: @Eendje No. you don't need cast again to [String]. I often make this for reading purpose.

Comment: This answer makes little sense. This takes an empty array of strings and tries to map each string by force-casting each string to a String array. That will fail for a couple of reasons.

Answer (score -1):

It can be so annoying to declare that I've resorted to declaring the data in a pList file and then simply reading it in to the variable.

You can use `contentsOfFile.

Here's a decent link to a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60804155/1058199
`