# Swift - Get .plist info and icon from .ipa

Tags: swift, objective-c, swiftui

I'm currently listing out downloaded .IPA files, but I need to get information from them.

Steps:

1 - List out downloaded files from documents directory IF they contain .ipa extension

2 - I need to read the info.plist and possibly fetch the app icon.

Here is as far as I am:

```swift
@State var appNames: [String] = []

            List(appNames, id: \.self) { app in
                HStack {
                    Image("placeholder")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 1.5))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                    VStack {
                        Text(app.description) // Default value: {{ app_name }}
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                        Text("{{ app_bundleid (app_version) }}")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.primary.opacity(0.6))
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                    }
               }
          }.onAppear() {
                do {
                    appNames = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: getDocumentsDirectory(),
                                                                           includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles).map {$0.lastPathComponent}
                    
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: If it helps the extension `.ipa` can be swapped with `.zip`

Comment: That was the first thought @Andrew, I'll definitely need to include some sort of unzip process in order to gain access to the files I need.

Comment: [ZipFoundation](https://github.com/weichsel/ZIPFoundation) is quite good at extracting zip files. You may want to move your logic to an ObservableObject as this could become quite intensive if there are many files to deal with.

Comment: This may help for reading the plist file once you have gotten it out of the `.ipa` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803515/swift-5-how-to-read-variables-in-plist-files